# What is the decimal point ('.') in C++ and can I make one?

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, decimal-point, punctuation

I am in a C++ class right now so this question will concern itself primarily with that language, though I haven't been able to find any information for any other language either and I have a feeling whatever the answer is it's probably largely cross language.

In C++ unmarked numbers are assumed to be of integral type ('4', for example, is an integer)
various bounding marks allow for the number to be interpreted differently (''4'', for example, is a character, '"4"' a string).

As far as I know, there is only one kind of unary mark: the decimal point. ('4.' is a double).

I would like to create a new unary mark that designates a constant number in the code to be interpreted as a member of a created datatype.  More fundamentally, I would like to know what the '.' and ',' and '"', and ''' are (they aren't operators, keywords, or statements, so what are they?) and how the compiler deals with/interprets them.

---

More information, if you feel it is necessary:

I am trying to make a complex number header that I can include in any project to do complex math.  I am aware of the  library but it is, IMHO, ugly and if used extensively slows down coding time.  Also I'm mostly trying to code this to improve my programming skills.  My goal is to be able to declare a complex variable by doing something of the form `cmplx num1= 3 + 4i;` where '3' and '4' are arbitrary and 'i' is a mark similar to the decimal point which indicates '4' as imaginary.

Comment: [User defined literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) will help you.

Comment: Your `complex` example already exists in C++14. The best you can get otherwise is `3 + 4_i`, or `3 + 4*i` for a more C-like way.

Comment: Is this some kind of wrapper around [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)?

Comment: The characters `.`, `,`, `"`, and so forth are part of the syntax of the language. The syntax is defined by the language and implemented by the compiler; it's generally not something you can change. As Jeffrey's answer says C++11 does have a feature (user defined literals) that let you do something like what you're looking for -- but they're really just part of the syntax of the language.

Comment: This question can be answered by studying a C++ reference manual, or the ISO C++ standard or a standard draft.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious And here I thought C++11 wasn't that big of an upgrade!  This is awesome, thanks.  It also allowed my to find the rest of the information I was looking for, because (unless I'm wrong) the decimal point (and other things) are specification-defined literals.  Bummer I have to include an underscore though.

Comment: The underscore requirement goes away in C++1y.

Comment: @chris,CaptainOblivious Ran into that while researching literals.  I'd prefer not to just use that library (since I was hoping to learn C++ better from this) but, because non-underscore-prefixed literals are reserved (and, more importantly, since the 'i' suffix has now apparently been defined within the standard) I'll probably have to capitulate and wait till... this year?  Anyways, I think I have everything I need, is there a way to close the question?  Should I move some of this information to an answer first?

Comment: @38806, Actually, both Clang and libc++ have fully implemented C++14 already (to the best of their ability what with it not being quite done yet), so if it's nothing important, there's not even need to wait until the end of Summer or whatever.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, You may just have a more updated C++14 spec than what I can find, but in N3797, §17.6.4.3.5/1 says: *Literal suffix identiﬁers that do not start with an underscore are reserved for future standardization.*

Comment: @chris I might be wrong (probably am) but I thought it had been changed to remove the underscore requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to create a new unary mark that designates a constant number in the code to be interpreted as a member of a created datatype.

You can use [*user defined literals*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) that were introduced in C++11. As an example, assuming you have a class type `Type` and you want to use the `num_y` syntax, where `num` is a `NumericType`, you can do:

```
Type operator"" _y(NumericType i) {
    return Type(i);
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c65d85dce9af1d0)

Comment: Is there any way to add prefix literals? Like `x_7` or `#8`

Comment: @awesomeyi, not that I know of, no.

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature is only with C++11.

Comment: Interesting, I've been used to putting a space between `operator""` and `_y` because GCC complains otherwise. Do you know offhand which one is correct?

Comment: @awesomeyi C++11 added user-defined literal suffixes.  There are still no user prefix literals, though there are system prefix literals like '"' and '''.

Comment: @chris, interesting question. The standard uses the space, so I guess it's probably better to go with the space.

Comment: @Jefffrey, Well, I looked at that section, and to be fair, it uses a space between `operator` and `""` as well. It makes the other space less meaningful to me.

Answer (score 1):

Things like `4`, `"4"` and `4.` are all single tokens,
indivisible.  There's no way you can add new tokens to the
language.  In C++11, it is possible to define user defined
literals, but they still consist of several tokens; for complex,
a much more natural solution would be to support a constant `i`,
to allow writing things like `4 + 3*i`.  (But you'd still need
the C++11 support for `constexpr` for it to be a compile time
constant.)